# Comment deletion rules

Tags: discussion, comments

I experienced deleted comments in the last few days and the last comment apparently was deleted automatically by the system. While searching on meta, I didn't find any information on how comments might get deleted.

As I understand comment deletion can be done by moderators, users and the system.

A moderator can delete any comment as he wishes.
Users can delete comments by flagging them, multiple flags might delete a comment. **Not sure on the rule to guess how much flags are needed to delete the comments.**

Users can also delete with one flag if the message has nuke keywords **(undefined list)** and it also might depend on the length of the comment.

The system might delete comment if they contain nuke words... mine contained the word "whore" as in "rep whore"... Could have been deleted for that reason. Note that the use of whore wasn't exactly rude or abusive.

Anyone came with a list of words or rules that could help us understand much how comments are getting deleted manually, semi-auto and automatically?

Comment: Assuming the comment you used was in reference to someones actions to gain rep so not sure how that would not be considered rude even if it was true.

Comment: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773)

Answer (score 14):

You appear to already know the real answer:

> Note that the use of whore wasn't exactly rude or abusive.

If you feel the need to explain away or otherwise excuse language that plainly isn't fit for polite company, you're Doing-It-Wrong™.

Use the comment feature the way it was meant to be used and you won't have these kinds of problems. Don't waste your time trying to figure out how to toe the line—just steer completely clear.

- Be nice.
- Be constructive.
- Use comments to request clarifications or suggest improvements and nothing else.

If you use the comment feature correctly, the finer details of comment moderation (whether automated or manual) won't give you any trouble. The only comment deletions you should be experiencing are ones flagged *‹obsolete›*, in which case you should be satisfied that they served their intended purpose.

Comment: well being nice is fine, but out of context, words have different meaning. Didn't know that there was such kind of filter. Unfortunately, it means that some commentaries might get removed out of context just because they contain certain words but they are by no mean "rude" or "abusive"...

Answer (score 2):

#### Extremely educated guess based on experience and observation.

Comments—as you should know—are never considered permanent and are often purged to keep things clean and not too chatty.

This should all be covered in the Meta Stack Exchange [“How do comments work?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) post as we all as [this discussion on policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199364/243319).

I believe that in general, only really, really, really bad comments that are obvious SPAM or have curse words in them get immediately deleted and are not noticed by most users. The rest are deleted at moderator discretion based on flags or just by their own observations from patrolling the site.

As far as deeper algorithmic logic goes, that is not ever revealed since it would compromise the whole security around the deletion system; if someone can “game” that then they can SPAM the site in comments and nobody is happy.

Comment: Well I guess that if it would allow baddies to game the algorithm and create much more problems... then I guess it's fine to keep it undisclosed.